# string or object in typescript resulting in error while accessing

Tags: javascript, typescript, definition

I have replicated the issue in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgIwgGwGp2QVwgZwCrjQC8UA3gFBRTKIoBcUOwATgJYB2A5lAD5lQAzAPZCGTNlygBfANzkpAbQC6cquQDGQ9kygA3DNhwN4SNAdwFIUEgtLVayBqWGioAcn1YIbqdIA0-DSmDB7mbtIq5OSehgB0ALZwYAAUntYAfGSUVFCa2kLIELHIQpypGMUOsQAWcDgA8gDu7AAKzEKQzKDJbi5uAJRQAPx6FUEosS5QDJ6Vpv3y-UA)

[image]

I tried with different safety checks before accessing the inner key, nothing helped.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't realize that `label.hasOwnProperty('foo')` necessarily implies that `label` is of type `{foo: string}`—it's complaining that you're trying to access `foo` on an object type (`string | {foo: string}`) for which one of the union types (`string`) doesn't have a property, `foo`. You have to explicitly cast.

Comment: How about trying this `value.map(v => typeof v.label == "object" ? v.label.foo : v.label)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `string` is simple type, you should check its type with `typeof`

```
type LabelValuesType2 = {
  label: string | { foo: string };
}[];

const values2: LabelValuesType2 = [{ label: { foo: 'value' } }, { label: 'value' }];

values2.map(val => {
  console.log(typeof val.label == 'string' ? val.label : val.label.foo)
})
```